# Hidden Button Saving

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, save, hidden

I have a group of buttons when clicked are hidden showing the underlying image. I need to know the best way to save their state so when restarted they do not revert to the unclicked view. Is this possible? Thank You.

```
-(IBAction)Act1 { 
Act1Button.hidden = YES;
}

-(IBAction)De1 {
Act1Button.hidden = NO;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // initialization
}
return self;
}


- (IBAction)savedata:(id)sender
{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setValue:@"myValue" forKey:@"mykey"];
[defaults synchronize];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![userDefaults valueForKey:@"mykey"]) {
    [userDefaults setValue:@"myValue" forKey:@"mykey"];
    NSLog(@"setting value");
}
[userDefaults synchronize];

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end

'@interface testViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIButton *Act1Button;
IBOutlet UIButton *De1Button;

}


@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Act1Button;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *De1Button;


- (IBAction)Act1;
- (IBAction)De1;

-(IBAction)savedata:(id)sender;


@end`
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, NSUserDefaults is used exactly for this purpose:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I've been reading that, but it makes no sense to me as where I need to put the codes. Do you have any examples? Also do I need to do this for each button? Thanks again.

Comment: every time someone presses a button, you write the state to NSUserDefaults and do a [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] ... that writes the current user defaults to persistent memory. When your app starts, you just read the state and act on it. It's difficult to get into it more without seeing your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I'm able to save and reload if I press my home button and restart the app, but if I go back to the menu screen I loose my changes. I added the code to the top. I'm really hoping you can help me! Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, so just re-apply those changes when your view appears. Again, it's difficult to tell you where to put this since it depends on your app but if your menu is just swapping UIViewControllers than restoring state in the viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear should handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you're missing the very important step of pulling the saved value(s) back out of Defaults when the app loads and doing something with them.

You should have something more like this:

```
-(IBAction)Act1 { 
  Act1Button.hidden = YES;
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setValue:Act1Button.hidden forKey:@"act1buttonState"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  Act1Button.hidden = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"act1buttonState"];
}
```

This way you're storing the state change every time a button is pressed, rather than needing a separate button to save (likely you'd move the save into it's own method that each button action would call). Also when you load the view back up again later, it's getting the state that was previously saved, and setting the buttons' visibilities to match.

This simple code would make you do it on an individual basis, so you should consider storing an NSDictionary in NSUserDefaults that holds the state for all the buttons. In viewDidLoad you could get that dictionary, and iterate over all it's values and set all the visibilities in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was wondering if you could possibly give me some examples of how I could save all the button states in one section of code. I have 50 states, I would like the user to press on each state individually hiding the button, to show the picture below. Then when they leave the app and return later, the button is still hidden. I have this, but when I restart the simulator no buttons are saved. Any help is appreciated.